# Classification of limit points

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, terminology

Let $X$ be a subset of a topolgical space with no open points. Then
$$\overline{X}=X_1\sqcup X_2\sqcup X_3\sqcup X_4\sqcup X_5$$
where $X_1$ are isolated points of $X$,
$X_2$ are interior points, $X_3=X\setminus(X_1\cup X_2)$,  $X_4$ are isolated points of the complement of $X$ and
$X_5$ are none of the above.

Are there one-word English names for points in
$X_3,X_4,X_5$ or some unions of these sets which actually appeared in the literature? Recall that the points in $\overline{X}$ are called *adherent*,  $\overline{X}\setminus X_1$ are the *limit points*, and $\overline{X}\setminus X_2$  are the *boundary points*. But I do not know if there are names for other subsets (besides $X=X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3$).

(This should probably be Community Wiki.)

Comment: i would call points in $X_4$ puncture points, $X_3$ - inner boundary, $X_5$ - outer boundary (but these are just my musings)